# Код работает на хостинге, но не работает локально

Tags: php, phpstorm

Есть html-страница:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="processorder.php" method = "post">
<table border = "0">
<tr bgcolor ="#cccccc">
    <td width="150">Product</td>
    <td width= "15">Quantity</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tyres</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="tireqty" size="3" maxlength="3"></td>
</tr>
</tr>
    <td>Oil</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="oilqty" size="3" maxlength="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>spark plug</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="sparkqty" size="3" maxlength="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="send order"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

К ней идет php файл

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Order result </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>auto parts</h1>
<h2>order results</h2>


<?php
$tireqty=$_POST['tireqty'];
$oilqty=$_POST['oilqty'];
$sparkqty=$_POST['sparkqty'];
echo "<p> order is processed at ";
    echo date('H:i, jS F Y');
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p> Ordered: </p>';
    echo $tireqty.' tires <br/>';
    echo $oilqty.' oil bottles <br/>';
    echo $sparkqty.' spark plugs <br/>';

?>

?>
</body>
</html>
```

При запуске с хостинга все работает, локально выдает ошибку:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\PHP\second\processorder.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in D:\PHP\second\processorder.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in D:\PHP\second\processorder.php
>   on line 14

Собственно ошибку он видит тут:

```
$tireqty=$_POST['tireqty'];
$oilqty=$_POST['oilqty'];
$sparkqty=$_POST['sparkqty'];
```

IDE - PhpStorm 2016.1 Веб-сервер - XAMP

Comment: Потому, что на хостинге выключено отображение ошибок наверное, вот вам и не высвечивает...а это в принципе не ошибка, а уведомление....А говорит оно о том, что нет такой переменной как `$_POST['tireqty']`, `$_POST['oilqty']` и другая из поста....а все потому. что на момент создания страницы их действительно нет...а появляются только тогда, когда вы отправляете пост запрос......соответственно надо проверять на существование...`$tireqty= isset($_POST['tireqty']) ? $_POST['tireqty'] :  'defaultValue'` и остальные также

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Это замечания о том, что элементы массива не инициализированные, скорее всего на хостинге эти замечания сыпятся в лог, поэтому вы их не замечаете. Хорошим тоном считается кодировать так, чтобы они не возникали, так как они указывают на потенциально опасные участки кода, которые в дальнейшем могут стать причиной ошибок. На момент первого запуска скрипта у вас нет данных в массиве `$_POST`, поэтому использовать его не корректно, хорошо, бы включать обработчик формы только в том случае, если POST-данные переданы, а каждый используемый элемент проверять на существование (например, при помощи конструкции `isset()`).

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)) {
  $tireqty  = isset($_POST['tireqty'])  ? $_POST['tireqty']  : '';
  $oilqty   = isset($_POST['oilqty'])   ? $_POST['oilqty']   : '';
  $sparkqty = isset($_POST['sparkqty']) ? $_POST['sparkqty'] : '';
  echo "<p> order is processed at ";
  echo date('H:i, jS F Y');
  echo '</p>';
  echo '<p> Ordered: </p>';
  echo $tireqty.' tires <br/>';
  echo $oilqty.' oil bottles <br/>';
  echo $sparkqty.' spark plugs <br/>';
}
```

Comment: Специально проверял на других машинах, все работает. Сделали виртуалку с Windows10, WebStorm, XAMP - ошибка воспроизводится.

Answer (score 0):

Удалил текущую версию PhpStorm и поставил 9-ю. Все работает.